# Display ubercart product image given a product nid

Tags: 6, ubercart

How do I display a product's image given the nid?

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky without some more information but something like this:

```
$product = node_load($nid);
$image_path = $product->field_image_cache[0]['filepath'];

print theme('imagecache', 'product', $image_path, $product->title, '');
```

Comment: So basically I just want to display the main image for a product when I have the product's nid.

Comment: If I remember right the above code should do that but I haven't used D6 in a while. Have you tried it?